# Use of struct identifier to signify POD types and C structures

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, visual-studio-2013, c++14

Consider the following piece of code:

```
struct Foo {};

template<typename ForwardIterator>
struct Foo*
Bar(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{ 
    (void)first;
    (void)last;
    Foo *foo(nullptr);
    return foo;
}
```

The above piece of code compiles fine in [Clangv3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73746ea02cc0781e) and [GCCv4.9](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73746ea02cc0781e).

However, it fails to compile in VC++2013.

Removing the `struct` identifier (see below) from the return type solves the problem:

```
struct Foo {};

template<typename ForwardIterator>
Foo*
Bar(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{ 
    (void)first;
    (void)last;
    Foo *foo(nullptr);
    return foo;
}
```

### **Q1:**

Is this a visual studio bug?

### **Q2:**

This issue came up, because in my code-base the `Foo` `struct` lies in a `.h.c` file (i.e., is a C `struct`) and in order to signify C/POD `struct`s in my code, I use the `struct` identifier. Is this a bad idea (i.e., in C++ code I should avoid to use `struct` identifier in this fashion)?

Comment: I often use `struct` in pure C++ code, in particular if there are no `private` or `protected` members or bases.

Comment: @Walter That’s not the point of the question here. It’s not `struct` vs `class`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Really? I thought the Q2 was essentially "*Is using `struct` exclusively for PODs a good idea?*" (If not used *exclusively* for that purpose, then the whole thing makes not sense.)

Comment: Let me know if you filled a bug report or not, otherwise I will file one.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour No I haven't, feel free to do so :).

Comment: @Walter Ah, I see the confusion. Given the context, I think OP knows the difference between `struct` and `class`, and that Q2 is asking whether it’s a good idea to prefix uses of a given struct name with the keyword `struct` (as need to be done in C).

Comment: I filed a bug report, it is linked in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main point of an *elaborated type specifiers* is to allow you refer to a name that has been hidden, from the [draft C++ standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b7b8ed08ba4c111ad03e13e8524a1b746cb74ec6/papers/N3936.pdf) section `3.4.4` *Elaborated type specifiers*:

> An elaborated-type-specifier (7.1.6.3) may be used to refer to a
>   previously declared class-name or enum-name even though the name has
>   been hidden by a non-type declaration (3.3.10).

and so in the case where `Foo` is hidden, you would have to use an *elaborated type specifiers*:

```
struct Foo {};

void Foo()
{
}
```

I see nothing in `7.1.6.3` *Elaborated type specifiers* or `14` *Templates* that would prevent this use. In fact it looks like from the description of [CS2989](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b25sbd9x.aspx) Visual Studio is getting confused and thinks you are attempting to redefine a non-template class as a template class.

So this looks like a bug to me, so I would file a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio).

**Update**

Filed a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1022916/using-an-elaborated-type-specifiers-as-a-return-type-in-a-template-function-does-not-work).