# Keyword enum starting a function definition in C++

Tags: c++, c, syntax, enums

I know that in both, C and C++, you may enumerate named constants with the `enum` keyword:

```
enum { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
```

If you don't assign a constant to the names, the compiler does it incrementally, starting at `0` for each new enumeration.

Now let's look on the differences:

```
enum COLOR { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
```

In C, COLOR is a so-called "tag". It cannot directly be used in variable or return type declarations. Instead you have to precede it by the `enum` keyword (or first make a `typedef` for it):

```
enum COLOR someCFunction();
```

In C++, enum-names are proper type names, so the `enum` is not necessary.

But you may nevertheless include it, and it seems to be syntactically correct and harmless:

```
enum COLOR someCppFunction();
```

Should I keep the `enum` keyword before enum-names in C++ code ("for compatibility reasons")?

Comment: Is this a general question for C++ programming or you do in fact expect to mix C and C++ in your project?

Comment: @NeilKirk the project moved from C to C++

Comment: I never do it. I don't think your C++ code will ever be "compatible" with C, anyway. What do you do, not use any std::vector just because C doesn't have them?

Comment: I think you should remove the C tag since the question only applies to C++. In C you'd have to use a typedef to "get rid of" the enum in front of the type.

Comment: If you are no longer using C, I would not do it.

Comment: This quesiton [Use of struct identifier to signify POD types and C structures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26755400/1708801) may be helpful

Comment: It depends, it could help reflect that the variable is an `enum`, you can do `typedef enum Color Color;` in c, and some people don't just to make it clear that `Color` variables are `enum`s. So this question is opinion based.

Comment: @DanielDaranas The "compatibility reasons" were a joke. I'd treat the surplus `enum` as an error, but I didn't want to change code just for "having a bad feeling".

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour indeed, but enum XYZ cannot be a forward declaration.

Comment: No.  Pick a language and go with it.

Comment: If "for compatibility reasons" were a joke, then the question is actually a bit different. I would not put the enum there "for compatibility reasons", but I would hesitate to alter old, tested code from C just to make it prettier.

Comment: @NeilKirk True. Now I have a problem with altering an old, tested question ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are the benefits? The ebenefits would be only if you compile the source with a C AND with a C++ compiler in different projects. Since you can also use `typedef` in C this is still not a really big benefit anyway, and this way it is more concise.

On the other hand, if you use the enum you have to REMEMBER that you do it conistently, otherwise you will have both versions, which can cause confusion and (in worst case) unexpected side effects, especially when sharing the code with multiple developers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this expresses my "feelings" best.

Comment: Personally I think you should always limit the stuff you have to remember because other people will not follow it and you have to check if it is enforced. Only do such things if you feel that they are absolutely neccessary for clearer code and/or are easily followed.

Comment: True, that's why I avoid `typedef`ing `struct`'s or `enum`'s

Answer (score 1):

Since you can do this in c

```
typedef enum Color Color;
enum Color {Red, Green, Blue, White, Black};
```

and then declare `enum`s of `Color` as

```
Color color;
```

then, the language is not the correct criterion for changing the syntax, if it is there it might be intentionally to make the reader aware of the fact, that these variables are `enum`s.

Comment: Good point. But today, [Artistic Style 2.05.1](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) failed formatting a function that started with `enum`, that's why I asked.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll have a look. BTW astyle is fine in letting things unchanged I don't specify: so I can introduce formatting rules incrementally.

Comment: @Wolf uncrustify has so many options, that when I use it, I just get bored of tuning it up, and leave defaults. And there was also a GUI based on Qt, so multiplatform, I just don't remember it's name.