# How can a same identifier be used for two different things in C & C++?

Tags: c++, c, uniqueidentifier, identifier

Sorry, If this type of question already asked on SO, but this is new for me when I tried following simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo()
{
    puts("foo() is invoked");
}
struct foo
{
    int a;
};
int main()
{
    struct foo f={3}; 
    printf("%d\n",f.a);
    foo();
}
```

Shouldn't we get an error? How it is possible to use same identifier for both function & struct in C & C++? What the C & C++ standard says about this?

Comment: Did you test this in C++ or just C?  I'm pretty sure it doesn't work in the former.

Comment: @jwodder: It works in both C & C++. I've tested it.

Comment: In C++ this is an [elaborated type specifier](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26758377/1708801) and that is the whole point to be able to refer to class or enum that is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag names (for structs, unions, and enums) occupy a different *name space* from identifiers (function, object, and typedef names).  Tag names are disambiguated by the presence of the `struct`, `union`, or `enum` keywords<sup>1</sup>.

Note that struct and union *member* names occupy yet another namespace and are disambiguated in expressions by the use of the `.` or `->` component selection operators, so the following code is legal (if a really bad idea):

```
struct foo { int foo; };
struct foo foo;
foo.foo = some_value();
```

The type name `struct foo` is disambiguated by the presence of the `struct` keyword, and the member name `foo.foo` is disambiguated by the presence of the `.` operator.

Here are the things you *cannot* do:

- You cannot use the same tag name for a struct *and* a union, or a struct *and* an enum, etc; IOW, you cannot do:

  ```
  struct foo { ... };
  enum foo { ... };
  union foo { ... };
  ```

  in the same code;

  You cannot use the same name for a typedef name *and* an object name:

  ```
  typedef struct foo { int foo; double bar; } foo;
  foo foo;
  ```

  You cannot use the same name for an enumeration constant and an object name:

  ```
  enum blurga { foo, bar, bletch } foo;
  ```

  You cannot use the same name for a function name and an object name:

  ```
  int foo() { ... }
  int bar()
  {
    int foo = foo();
  }
  ```

---

<sup>1.  I'm *assuming* this is also the case for the `class` keyword in C++, but I don't have that reference handy.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The name of the type is `struct foo`; i.e., when referring to the struct, `foo` is always preceded by `struct`, so it's unambiguously the struct and not the function.  Moreover, since this isn't C++, declaring `struct foo` does not make `foo` a name for the type, so a plain `foo` can only refer to the function.  You'll only get problems if you try to do:

```
typedef struct foo {
    int a;
} foo;
```